# Triangular link area

Tags: css, css-shapes

Consider the following shapes:

[image: CSS triangle area]

1. The grey area is an outside container. Disregard that.
2. The white area is a link (`a` tag).
3. The red triangular area is another link (`a` tag).

I have created a CSS triangle for the red area using the following code:

```
.ribbon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    border-left: 60px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 60px solid red;
}
```

The problem is that in the following image, the **link doesn't maintain it's boundaries in the red triangle shape**. The in green triangle is also clickable :

[image: maintain the click boundaries in the triangle]

Question is:
How do I make the red area link to one location, and the white to another, without having the browser count the green area in the second illustration as part of the red area?

Comment: Check this [site](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/)

Comment: I think you'd have to put in another element in the green area on top of the red. It will take the clicks and not allow clicks underneath. Sort of like when you have an element set to `visiblity: none;` I haven't tried this but I think it will wokr.

Comment: Have you considered using an image map? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map

Comment: You make your red link a square, and rotate it to 45°.

Comment: why not use an old fashioned `map` http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_area_coords.asp

Answer (score 15):

The border technique won't allow you to maintain the boundaries of the hover and click event inside the triangular shape. You can use transform rotate on the link combined with `oveflow:hidden;` on the parent element to allow click and hover event only inside the triangle :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/het0a76n/)**

```css
html,body{
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
div{
    height:90%;
    border:10px solid lightgrey;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
a{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%; height:20%;
    background:red;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0;
    transform-origin: 100% 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div>
    <a href="#"></a>
</div>
```

This solution is adapted from this answer : [CSS triangles with transform rotate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073484/how-does-this-css-triangle-shape-work/24808936#24808936).

---

**EDIT :**

This demo shows you can differenciate the click envent between gold and red areas :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/het0a76n/6/)**

```css
#area {
    height:50%;
    border:10px solid lightgrey;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.gold{
    display:block;
    height:100%;
    background:gold;
}
.red {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%; height:20%;
    background:red;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0;
    transform-origin: 100% 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
/* FOLLOWING JUST FOR THE DEMO */
 html, body {height:100%;margin:0;padding:0;overflow:hidden;}
a{color:teal;text-decoration:none;font-family:arial;font-size:20px;padding:5%;text-align:center;}
#goldLink, #redLink {position:absolute;top:50%;left:100%;width:100%;text-align:center;}
#goldLink:target {background:gold;left:0;}
#redLink:target {background:red;left:0;}
```

```html
<div id="area"> 
    <a class="gold" href="#goldLink">
        Click gold and red areas to see the diference.<br/>
        Triangular boundaries are maintained.
    </a>
 <a class="red" href="#redLink"></a>
</div>
<!-- FOLLOWING JUST FOR DEMO !-->
<h1 id="goldLink">Gold area clicked</h1>
<h1 id="redLink">Red area clicked</h1>
```

Comment: +1 for using the code snippet. And for having a working solution of course.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a solution using `transform: skew`: http://jsfiddle.net/0a8aq5ve/.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <a href = ""></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

div > a {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    transform-origin: bottom left;
    transform: skewX(-45deg);
}
```

Comment: This solution allows the whole thing to be `position: fixed` which is a win.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
.triangle { 
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-bottom: 100px solid red;
 border-left: 100px solid transparent;
 }
```

Comment: Doesn't work. The "opposite" triangle (green in the illustration) still links to the wrong page.

Answer (score 0):

Try that, instead of making a CSS triangle with borders, make a square `a` and rotate it to 45°:

```
.ribbon {
position: absolute;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
width: 60px;
height: 60px;
transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

And be sure to make the parent `overflow: hidden;` or all the red square will be visible :)