# navigate on triangle click

Tags: html, css

I have shape of triangle on which click I want client to navigate in another page.

But link goes in whole square. How can I solve that?

my div is:

```
div{
    border-bottom: 50px solid red;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    line-height: 75px;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/1vnmhyw0/18/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a repeating question:
[Triangular link area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25917610/triangular-link-area)

Insert the link into the div

Use skew or rotate:
http://jsfiddle.net/0a8aq5ve/

```
html,body {
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
div {
    height:50%;
    border:10px solid lightgrey;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
a {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%; height:20%;
    background:red;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0;
    transform-origin: 100% 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

Comment: if you know the question to be a dupe please don't reanswer the question - It would be best to VTC as dupe as OP will be able to find their answer in a single link.